# Counting number of co-ordinates in hypercube

Tags: algorithm, math

In an N-dimensional grid the co-ordinates of a cell are denoted as X1, X2, ..., XN. Any cell with negative co-ordinate are colored white. The origin cell (the one with all zero co-ordinates) is colored as black. The color of a cell in (X1, X2, ..., XN) depends on the N cells with co-ordinates (X1-1, X2, ..., XN), (X1, X2-1, ..., XN), ...., (X1, X2, ..., XN-1). The cell is colored white if and only if the number of black colored cells among these N co-ordinates are even, otherwise the cell is colored black.

Now, given the starting and ending co-ordinate of sub-hypercube. All the co-ordinates will be non negative integers for which the query is done. We've to compute how many hyper cells in this sub hypercube are colored black?

Please suggest me hint, reference or anything which could help me to solve it.

Comment: What means `any cell with negative coordinate`? Any cell that has *at least* one negative coordinate or that has *only* negative coordinates?

Comment: Any cell coordinate consists of n-components. this refers to if any of the component is negative.

Comment: Ok, and what's a *starting* and *ending* coordinate of a hypercube? I thougt a hypercube is `{0,1}^n` (i.e. only 0-1-tuples of length n). How's your definition of (sub)hypercube?

Comment: "starting" and "ending" coordinates are given and 0-1 tuples of length n refers to "unit hypercube".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule results in a well known fractal - [The Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle)

Here is an image of it in 2D:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A brute force algorithm:

```
fill the hypercube (the needed part) with value 'unknown'.
color[00000] = 1  #black

sum = 0
for each cell in sub-hypercube:
   sum += getcolor(cell)
   return sum

getcolor(cell):
   if color[cell] == unknown
      c = 0  #white
      for each neighbour cell in decreasing direction within non-negative boundary:
          c = c xor getcolor(neighbour)
      color[cell] = c
   return color[cell]
```